# Fetching the data from AWS S3 bucket using command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws s3api select-object-content     --bucket myaws-bucket10     --key
data.csv     --expression "select _1,_2 from s3object s GROUP BY _2
ORDER BY _2 DESC"     --expression-type 'SQL'    
--input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}'     --output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "/tmp/output.csv"
```

I am using this command to fetch the 1st and 2nd column from data.csv and doing group by and order by 2nd column. Its giving me error.

An error occurred (ParseUnexpectedToken) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Unexpected token found KEYWORD:order at line 1, column 42.

Answer (score 1):

S3 Select supports a limited subset of the SQL dialect, and `ORDER BY` is not a [supported S3 Select SQL operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference.html). I assume this is because S3 select works by  reading one line of data at a time and streaming that to the response, while `ORDER BY` would require S3 to read the entire content of the file into memory and sort it before returning anything.